# DBSCAN Input explaination

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan

What exactly does the *DBSCAN* algorithm take as input?

Why do I have different output in `weka` and in a coded algorithm?

In a coded algorithm, it only takes 2 inputs while in `weka` it could take 3.

Can someone help me understand the algorithm please?

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is described pretty well in the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN). The configuration input is:

- `eps`: Maximum distance for the epsilon neighborhood.
- `minPts`: The number of points which are required to form a region.

Briefly: A new cluster is created, if the epsilon neighborhood around a data point contains at least `minPts`. Further input:

- the dataset (obviously)
- (maybe) a distance function, if the algorithm allows parametrizing in that regard

Comment: What I mean to ask is that I have 3 variables as my input. In a coded DBSCAN algorithm, it only takes 2 as input. what should I do?

Comment: This cannot be answered without knowing what those parameters are (name, type, documentation, etc.).

Comment: well, I have course, interests(a set of interest) and club. I am trying to cluster the interest of club members related to their clubs

Comment: If you have the source code, try to compare with the pseudo code given in the Wikipedia article. This way, you should be able to reverse engineer the meaning of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

With "2 inputs", do you mean two *variables* (dimensions), by chance?

If your code only works with 2 dimensions, read up on distance functions. Most distance functions can be computed for more than two dimensions easily... for example, Euclidean distance is defined as

```
sqrt(pow(x_i-y_i, 2).sum())
```

which works well when you loop i from 1 to n > 2, too.

DBSCAN has 2 obvious and one hidden parameter: minPts, and epsilon are the obvious ones, and the hidden parameter is the *distance function*. Which has by far the largest effect on the results, and requires data understanding to choose. There is no rule of thumb to choose this parameter, unfortunately. It really depends on your data.

I'm not surprised if you get different results in the Weka implementation. It contains implicit data normalization, which tends to produce unexpected results... The best implementation of DBSCAN can IMHO be found in [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/). If you enable data indexes, it is really fast.

Comment: thanks for responding. one more thing: what part of the code should I put the Euclidean distance formula? Is it in my regionQuery() function?